# Do all collections accounts show up on a credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-report, collections

When running credit reports for potential tenants, I sometimes see accounts which are closed and charged off as a "profit and loss write-off".  I also sometimes see collection accounts.  That being the case, is it possible that some of the items which have been charged off as a loss could still be passed off to a collection agency which is not showing up on the credit report in the USA?  That is, do all collection accounts always show up on an individual's credit report?

Comment: A debt that has been charged off is still owed and can still be collected. The charge off just means that the party the money is owed to has declared they no longer have an expectation of being paid. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-off) for more details.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example the company that sent an account to collections may not have enough information to report that account to the credit bureaus.

There may be other companies that have sufficient information to report the accounts but choose not to for various reasons likely relating to the cost of processing or the cost of potential penalties if the information is not reported completely accurately.

Answer (score 1):

In short, [no](http://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/collection-account-does-not-have-to-appear-on-your-credit-report-to-be-legitimate/), not all collection accounts will show up on a credit report.

> Reporting payment information to a credit reporting company is not
>   required by law....